# What is the basic setup for securing PowerBI reports?

Tags: powerbi

We are looking at the possible migration of reports from our reporting platform to PowerBI and have got PowerBI Desktop installed for a few quick tests; made a database connection, written a simple report and published it successfully. In this process, it has raised the question of what we would need to do, to restrict access to the reports we create for users outside of our organisation?

Someone mentioned that we need a PowerBI server, but cannot find a straight forward answer to confirm that and to identify what needs to be installed, etc.,

If we can get a bit of a "dummies guide to setting up" or reference to an article that explains in fairly simple terms that would be great.

Comment: You can use row level security, do a search and you will learn what it is about

Comment: what is your source database?

Comment: We're running a MySQL DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do three things for users outside your organisation:

1) You can use [Azure Active Directory B2B](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-azure-ad-b2b), to add in external users and allocated the a Power BI Pro Licences and the secure the reports the normal way on a workspace or app

2) You can use [Power BI Embedded](https://www.codemag.com/Article/1905061/Creating-Embedded-Reports-in-Your-Web-Apps-with-Power-BI-Embedded) A SKU's. Using this service you can create a web portal that uses this to display your own reports. You have to build you own front end, user login etc, it will just show the reports

3) You can use Power BI Report Server (PBRS) as an [external website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms159272(v=sql.105)), you'll still need to add users to AD, but they don't have to be pro users. The link is for SSRS 2008, but most of it should apply as PBRS is a superset of SSRS